# Mac OS X data type for YUV video frame

Tags: macos, cocoa, video

Is there a data type for storing a video frame in a YUV 420 format in (64-bit) Mac OS X?

Comment: Are you working with any specific library?

Comment: No. I'm updating code that was using QuickTime to be 64-bit compatible.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with storing it architecture-indendent? While there is e.g. `CVPixelBuffer` with `kYUV420PixelFormat`, it doesn't exactly make things simpler.

Comment: Simpler than what? An architecture-independent storage type? What would you suggest? Would you mind explaining in an answer?

Comment: With the above you still have to setup the storage yourself. I'm still unsure what your actual problem is - what prevents you from just putting buffer + dimensions + possibly offsets in e.g. a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It's the `CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrPlanar` struct declared in the CoreVideo library's CVPixelBufferPool.h